# Count distinct values in pyspark streaming with window

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I want to count distinct column values from window, but when I run query it gives error as

> pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException:
> [NESTED_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION] It is not allowed to use an aggregate
> function in the argument of another aggregate function. Please use the
> inner aggregate function in a sub-query.;

Here is code :

```
def check_value(col: Column):
    return f.when(f.size(col) > 1, f.lit(None)).otherwise(f.first(col))

cols = [check_value(col) for col in columns]
window = Window.orderBy(..............)
df.withWatermark(column_name, time).groupby(
               window
            ).agg(
                f.to_json(f.struct(*cols)).alias(
                    distinct_vals
                )
            )
```